# Stream grep from subprogram, not tail file

Tags: shell, grep

Does a simple one liner exist for grepping continuous output from a program rather than just a file?

Now just as an example, I would like to skip lines containing `PHPUnit` in them. For obvious reasons the following gist does not do that:

```
phpunit tests/cases | grep -v --line-buffered "PHPUnit"
```

Can it be done as a universally usable oneliner, without user defined functions and so?

Comment: Why does it not work?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas oh the test prints the content over like 15 minutes, by characters. I have no idea how grep is implemented, but I guess it can't really do much once the characters are printed.

Comment: May be the test cases output to STDERR? How does `phpunit test/cases 2>&1 | grep -v "PHPUnit"` fair?

Comment: So what's going on: do you get no output at all? too much output? the right output but delayed? something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like the output from your phpunit command is getting buffered (either by PHP, the Bash shell, or `grep`). There are a couple of ways to unbuffer the output so that it's more responsive.

#### unbuffer

You could try using the [`unbuffer`](http://expect.nist.gov/example/unbuffer.man.html) command which is part of [`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/).

```
$ unbuffer phpunit tests/cases | grep -v --line-buffered "PHPUnit"
```

#### stdbuf

You can try using the `stdbuf` command to disable the buffering.

```
$ stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 phpunit tests/cases | grep -v --line-buffered "PHPUnit"
```

Details of the switches:

```
   -i, --input=MODE
          adjust standard input stream buffering

   -o, --output=MODE
          adjust standard output stream buffering

   -e, --error=MODE
          adjust standard error stream buffering
```

So the above sets the buffering for STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR is set to zero.

#### grep

Grep itself might be the culprit in buffering output. You can tell it to buffer only a line at a time's worth of output. (This one you've already mentioned/discovered but I'm mentioning it so that future viewers of this Q&A will understand that there is buffering there too).

```
$ phpunit tests/cases | grep -v --line-buffered "PHPUnit"
```